# Passing data from MDI Child to MDI Parent

Tags: c#, mdi, mdichild, mdiparent

I new some help to pass data from my mdi child to the mdi parent.
And I want to show the string (on the mdi parent) that I wrote in the mdi child.
I also have to make the string appear after close the mdi child.

[image: Example]

Any help?

Comment: Would be better if we see your work..

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mma1979/how-to-access-mdiparent-controls-from-child-forms/

Answer (score 0):

From the parent form you can access the parent form my name

```
Form frm = (Form)Application.OpenForms["ParentFormName"];
```

Comment: Well, don't do that, it is simply this.MdiParent in a child form.

Answer (score 0):

Just declare a variable in parent with internal access and assign values of child form to that variable. You should be good to use the value on parent form.